# The correct way to bind object to Promise.then() argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, this, bluebird

I found out the hard way that one can't simply just pass in a object's function into the Bluebird `then`. I'm assuming that Bluebird's `then` is doing some magic and wrapping the passed in function in an anonymous function. So I attached a `.bind` to the function and it worked. Is this the correct way to do this with bluebird? Or is there some better way?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")

var Chair = function(){
  this.color = "red"
  return this
}


Chair.prototype.build = function(wood){
  return this.color + " " + wood
}

var chair = new Chair()

//var x = chair.build("cherry")

Promise.resolve("cherry")
  .then(chair.build.bind(chair)) // color is undefined without bind
  .then(console.log)
```

I know none of this is async so please bare with the sync example, my usage is async.

Comment: Haven't heard of Bluebird, but if its Promises follow the Promise pattern as implemented by jQuery, then this is the way to go, as long as you're targeting modern browsers which support `Function.bind` (otherwise you'd need to roll your own, or use Underscore for a `bind` shim)

Comment: Sure. If @thefourtheye is right and this `Promise` has its own `bind` feature, I'd probably use that instead.

Comment: @Lambart Its a bluebird specific function :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> So I attached a `.bind` to the function and it worked. Is this the correct way to do this with bluebird?

Yes, that is one way to retain the context. You can also pass an anonymous function (you might already know this).

```
Promise.resolve("cherry")
    .then(function (value) {
        return chair.build(value);
    })
    .then(console.log);
```

> Or is there some better way?

You can actually use bluebird's [`Promise.bind`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) method, like this

```
Promise.resolve("cherry")
  .bind(chair)
  .then(chair.build)
  .then(console.log)
```

Now, whenever the Promise handlers (fulfill handlers or rejection handlers) are called, inside the function, `this` will refer the `chair` object only.

---

<sub>**Note 1:** In this specific case, `console.log` also gets `this` as `chair` object, but it still works fine, because, in Node.js, `console.log` function is defined not only on the prototype bu also on the object itself, bound to the `console` object. The corresponding code is [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L46-L53).</sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** If different handlers need different contexts, then better write anonymous functions. In that case, `Promise.bind` will not help much. But if you choose to use it, then you have to use different contexts for each of the handlers and your code might look something like this</sub>

```
var chair1 = new Chair("red")
var chair2 = new Chair("green")

Promise.resolve("cherry")
    .bind(chair1)            // Changing the binding to `chair1`
    .then(chair1.build)
    .tap(console.log)
    .bind(chair2)            // Changing the binding to `chair2`
    .then(chair2.build)
    .tap(console.log);
```